# Linux ifconfig - what does ifconfig | grep -Po "HWaddr \K.*$"

Tags: linux, ifconfig

I was hoping somebody could explain bit by bit what each part of this command does.

> `ifconfig | grep -Po "HWaddr \K.*$"`

e.g. what The `-Po` is for?

Comment: What research have you done so far on this?

Comment: I found that -P is short for `--perl-regexp` and means "Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE).". -o is short for `--only-matching` and means "Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines...".

Answer (score 5):

## What does this command do?

`ifconfig | grep -Po "HWaddr \K.*$"`

prints out the MAC/hardware addresses of active network interfaces present on your system, if available.

---

As an aside, in Linux in general you can find out about programs and what their switches do by looking them up in `man`, eg:

> `$ man ifconfig`
>
> `$ man grep`

*(etc)* Failing that, a search for '`<program name>` manual' or '`<program name>` usage' can answer these sorts of questions.

## ifconfig

`ifconfig` is used to display and configure network interfaces. From `man ifconfig`:

> Ifconfig  is  used to configure the kernel-resident network interfaces.  It is used at boot time to set up interfaces as necessary.  After that, it is usually only needed when debugging or when  system  tuning  is needed.
>
> **If  no  arguments are given, ifconfig displays the status of the currently active interfaces**.  If a single interface argument is given, it displays the status of the given interface only; if a single  -a argument    is given, it displays the status of all interfaces, even those that are down.  Otherwise, it configures an      interface.

*(emphasis mine)*

Here, `ifconfig` is reporting the status of your currently active interfaces.

## | (pipe)

The pipe character - `|` - here [redirects the output](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_05_01.html) from `ifconfig` and instead of it being displayed to you, it instead goes to `grep`

## grep

`grep` is used for pattern matching, and (usually) printing what matches a pattern or not.

Here, the options supplied are `-P` and `-o`

**`-P`**:

> Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  This is highly experimental  and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.

Regexes are a long topic<sup>1</sup>, but basically, this lets `grep` match some additional patterns.

**`-o`**:

> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each  such  part  on  a  separate output line.

*(both quotes from grep manpage)*

This option tells `grep` that we're only interested in the part that matches the pattern, as opposed to the whole line (if it matches).

## "HWaddr \K.*$"

This part is what tells us we are looking for the `HWaddr` (MAC or hardware address). `\K` sets the start point of what we want printed (for the `-o` option above). `.*` tells `grep` to match any character (`.`) as many times as possible (`*`), at least until the end of the line (`$`).

## Output / Result

Putting it all together, the command takes information from `ifconfig` and searches for the parts matching the MAC address of network interfaces on the system, and prints those out each on a new line.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."
*Jamie Zawinski, 1997* (although the quote is often [taken out of context](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/))</sup>